# Страница рендерится быстрее, чем приходят данные с сервера

Tags: angular2, typescript

Angular 6. Страница рендерится быстрее, чем приходят данные с сервера. На странице у меня есть сообщение, если сервер ничего не вернул:

```
<div *ngIf="user != null; else noEntityBlock" class="row">
  ...
</div>

<ng-template #noEntityBlock>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">There are no user with this ID.</div>
</ng-template>
```

Как я понимаю, объект `user` создаётся при вызове конструктора, тогда же и рендерится страница, и срабатывает `ngIf`, но ответ от сервера приходит чуть позже и страница обновляется. Наверное есть вариант с лодером, но мне не очень хочется показывать лодер на каждой странице. Какие тут есть вариант ожидания загрузки? Такая же проблема и с куки, когда страница рендерится быстрее, чем ставятся новые куки и приходится её повторно обновлять, чтобы отобразить актуальную информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть, использовать `Resolver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно дождаться ответа от сервера и тогда показывать либо данные, либо ошибку о недоступности данных:

```
public userNotFound = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.GetUserById(id).subscribe(x => {
    if (x != null) {
      this.user = x;
    } else {
      this.userNotFound = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
<div *ngIf="!userNotFound; else noEntityBlock" class="row">

</div>

<ng-template #noEntityBlock>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">There are no user with this ID.</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: просто используйте резолверы, они решают именно такие проблемы - грузят данные на определенном этапе жизненного цикла роутера перед инициализацией компонента

Comment: у меня не было времени на изучение Resolver'ов сейчас. Так что ответ дал такой, в дальнейшем постараюсь заюзать их

Answer (score -1):

попробуй без else

```html
<div *ngIf="user?.id" class="row">
  ...
</div>



 <div *ngIf="!user?.id" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">There are no user with this ID.</div>
```

Comment: Минусовал не я, но и плюсовать не за что. Ваш вариант от моего не отличается, работает так же.